# Pycharm Django Supervisor Manage.py

Tags: django, pycharm, supervisord

I'm using Pycharm Professional edition to maintain a Django web application hosted on a remote Linux OS. Until now I've used Expandrive to mount the remote volume as a local windows mapped drive and can use remote debugging.

However I would like to develop locally and deploy to the server which I've got working but struggling to configure the run/debug configuration in conjunction with the Django settings in preferences considering I use supervisor to control all the processes.

1. Here's a screenshot of my deployment configuration (connection)

[image: Deployment configuration - connection]

2. Here's a screenshot of my deployment configuration (mappings)

[image: Deployment configration - mappings]

3. Here's a screenshot of run/debug configuration

[image: Run/debug configuration]

When I enable django support, point to my manage.py script and run the configuration it tries to run using manage.py whereas I want it to use the supervisor script. So I therefore get this:

[image: Error - port is already in use]

**However the real problem is I would like to control the remote supervisor from pycharm**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have edited the OP, thanks

Comment: There is still no question in the text you have written. Please be specific and ask a concrete question. Include relevant code, expected behavior and the current behavior. Include _everything_ we need to know to help you. This question is too broad for StackOverflow and will **not** be answered in its current form. Please read the guidelines and the help section or delete the question.

Comment: ok will do. thank you

Comment: Hi OptimusCrime, have updated the OP. Many thanks.